# Can I add two propertyChangeListener in order

Tags: java

Can I add two propertyChangeListener to JFormattedField and be sure in order how they are going to be executed ?

Comment: why don't you call the two methods consequently in the one property listener?

Comment: Notification sequence is undefined, technically -as already stated - solvable by some kind of controller which dispatches the events in a pre-defined sequence. But the real question is: why do you think you need it? Think about re-designing so you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

After wracking my brain on this one ... long time since I've looked at it.

Ultimately you're going to be using Component's proppertyChange handling.

If you use the PropertyChangeSupport object, this is ultimately backed by [sun.awt.EventListenerAggregate](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/awt/EventListenerAggregate.java.html). This contains an array of PropertyChangeListeners.

When an event is fired, the listeners are notified in the order in which they were added to the aggregate.

Comment: I think that this is implementation defined behaviour that you should not rely on. Might change in future versions without notification.

Comment: Agreed. I believe though that the default PropertyChangeSupport utilizes a FIFO behavior. @Axel makes a very important point. This is a sun.awt class which is subject to change with little or no notice. The class that I referenced above was introduced in Java 1.5 (according to its @since javadoc annotation). With this in mind, you may want to look at the history of the PropertyChangeSupport object and see how it has evolved.